# Nodogsplash with time limit

Tags: router, openwrt

I'm using Nodogsplash in a router with OpenWRT to create a Wi-Fi Hotspot which will serve free wi-fi for a people who visit the Theater of my city.

But what I would like to is if there's someway to create a limit of 15 minutes and then block the MAC address until the next day. How can I do that using nodogsplash?

Answer (score 0):

yep that's possible. At least the time limit. I already found out. I'm not sure about that mac but check the .conf file. it's all in there. look for this line:

```js
# Parameter: ClientForceTimeout
# Default: 360
#
# Set ClientForceTimeout to the desired number of minutes before
# a user is automatically 'deauthenticated', whether active or not
#
# ClientForceTimeout 360
```